# heroku messing up image formatting

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

i am having trouble with heroku messing up my image formatting. i don't get any image problems in my localhost development.

so if you visit [novulty.herokuapp.com/services](http://novulty.herokuapp.com/services) and scroll to the 'our results' section, you'll see that some of the logos are wrongly formatted. if you keep refreshing the page, you'll see different logos get wrongly formatted. i am really not sure what the case is.

i've tried precompiling my assets (`rake assets:precompile`) but that doesn't seem to be do the trick. next, i thought it was an issue of loading my javascript later as opposed to earlier in the file, but if i load it in the beginning (in the `<head>`) the javascript doesn't even work... so i am very confused.

feel free to take a look at my code at https://github.com/sambaek/novulty

could anyone help me? thanks!

### UPDATE:

this problem is happening on localhost. a lot less often though. i wonder if it's a javascript/css issue or rails/heroku one?

Comment: It does seem like it might be some sort of race condition with your javascript. Can you please post your javascript so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely your issue has to do with running in Production versus Development, and the order in which your assets are being read. In development, the order works, but in Production, where your css and javascript is likely all concatenated into single files, you might be overriding classes and having other conflicts.

To test this theory, just run locally your app in production. I don't do this often, but the commands are likely

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precomiple
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

Assuming that you'll see the same errors, you might next figuring out if its your CSS or javascript. Inspect your images and make sure the classes and attributes are as you expect. Check for overwritten classes.

Lastly, if still an issue, I'd focus on your javascript. Remember that if you put it into multiple js files, they'll all be combined into 'application.js', assuming you are using the default setup. If you have a developer mode on your browser (I use Chrome), check the javascript inspector to see for any errors.

Comment: it turned out to be a problem with my css. it was a lot of conflicting classes and display parameters (some inline, some inline-block, etc.). so big thanks for the direction. and the production environment on localhost setup helped a lot! thanks!